# Exporting GridView to Excel using EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, epplus

I am trying to export gridview to excel and when I convert a Gridview to datatable. I have a value of nothing in datatable. Below is my code:

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    FormatUtility.DateFormat(Date.Today.Month, dateMM)
    FormatUtility.DateFormat(Date.Today.Day, dateDD)
    ' Dim dvExWrd As New DataView
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridData.xlsx")
    FormatExcelTransfer()
    Dim GV As GridView = CType(Session("GridView"), GridView) ' I checked, I have the value in GV
    Dim dt As DataTable = TryParse(GV.DataSource, DataTable) 'I have a value of nothing in dt

    Using pck As New ExcelPackage()

        Dim wsDt As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
        wsDt.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True, TableStyles.None)
        wsDt.Cells(wsDt.Dimension.Address).AutoFitColumns()

        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
    End Using

    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Dim GV As GridView = CType(Session("GridView"), GridView) ' I checked, I have the value in GV
         Dim dt As DataTable = TryParse(GV.DataSource, DataTable) 'I have a value of nothing in dt

I am not sure what am I doing wrong or if there is any other way to convert Gridview to DataTable and the way, I am using is wrong

Comment: You should not convert a GridView. A GridView is a UI control. You can just export the DataTable directly. Anyways, we can't tell you what's wrong unless you show the relevant code, meaning your `TryParse` function.

Comment: I applied lot of formatting things on the gridview and I want those to be exported to gridview for e.g. rows color and the caption. I just put TryParse, this is not a function. Basically how can I convert a gridview to datatable

Comment: GridView is HTML, the formatting isn't directly applicable to Excel. They have different methods of being styled. Again, *forget about the GridView*. Just style the Excel sheet directly using the API provided by EPPlus.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I can put the row color, but i need to put gridview caption too.I guess, I need to merge the Excel cells for that.